# Detecting when the mouse is not moving

Tags: javascript, events, mouse

I am able to find the cursor position. But I need to find out if the mouse is stable. If the mouse wasn't moved for more than 1 minute, then we have to alert the user.

How its possible, are there any special events for this? (Only for IE in javascript)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Set a timeout when the mouse is moved one minute into the future, and if the mouse is moved, clear the timeout:

```
var timeout;
document.onmousemove = function(){
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = setTimeout(function(){alert("move your mouse");}, 60000);
}
```

Comment: I see a potential problem: Every call to setTimeout returns a number for a counter. When will it wrap around and what happens then? I suggest a setInterval(update,1000) instead, where 'update' increments a variable that the onmousemove event resets. If the variable gets over 60 in update, alert user

Answer (score 3):

**Here's a one-and-done function that can check any element for movement:**

```
function mouse (element, delay, callback) {

   // Counter Object
   element.ms = {};

   // Counter Value
   element.ms.x = 0;

   // Counter Function
   element.ms.y = function () {

      // Callback Trigger
      if ((++element.ms.x) == delay) element.ms.callback(element, element.ms);
   };

   // Counter Callback
   element.ms.callback = callback;

   // Function Toggle
   element.ms.toggle = function (state) {

      // Stop Loop
      if ([0, "off"][state]) clearInterval(element.ms.z);

      // Create Loop
      if ([1, "on"][state]) element.ms.z = setInterval(element.ms.y, 1);
   };

   // Function Disable
   element.ms.remove = function () {

      // Delete Counter Object
      element.ms = null; return delete element.ms;
   };

   // Function Trigger
   element.onmousemove = function () {

      // Reset Counter Value
      element.ms.x = -1;
   };

   // Return
   return element.ms;
};
```

**Usage:**
`mouse(element, delay, callback)`

**Examples:**
*Make a video player hide the mouse after 5 seconds when idle and fullscreen*

```
let x = mouse(video, 5000, function (a) {
   if (document.webkitIsFullScreen) video.style.cursor = "none";
});

x.toggle(1); addEventListener("mousemove", function () {
   video.style.cursor = "auto";
});
```

*Chat Room AFK (45 Seconds) (assuming you have a chat box and a send message function):*

```
let x = mouse(chatBox, (45e3), function (a) {
   chatBox.send({ text: chatBox.username + " is AFK.", italic: true });
});

x.toggle(1); x.addEventListener("mousemove", function () {
  chatBox.send({ text: chatBox.username + " is no longer AFK", italic: true });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there not a way to set a timer to start incrementing after every mouse movement event?

If it gets to a minute then pop up the message box, but every time the mouse moves the timer gets reset.

Answer (score 1):

Use a timer that resets its value on mousemove event.
If timer reaches 1 minute --> Do something.

More info on **timer** here http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp
And more info on **catchin mouse events** here http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_mouse.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have a onmousemove event in Javascript, so to achieve what you need you just have to do code something like this:

```
startTimer();
element.onmousemove = stopTimer(); //this stops and resets the timer
```

You can use it on the document body tag for instance.

UPDATE: @Marius has achieved a better example than this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onmousemove event. Inside it, clearTimeout(), and setTimeout(your_warning, 1 minute).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [this script/snippet](http://www.codelifter.com/main/javascript/capturemouseposition1.html) to detect the mouse pointer position and "remember" it. Then use a timer "setTimeout(...)" to check the position let's say every second and remember that time.

If more than one minute passed and the position hasn't changed, you could alert the user.