# How to make function work when the mouse not moving?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var score = 0;

    $("body").mousemove(function() {        
        score++;
        $("#result").val(score);
        console.log(score);
    });

 });
```

The score will increase every time when I move the mouse, but how should I add a function to decrease the score until 0 when the mouse is not moving?

Comment: use `setTimeout` or `setInterval`.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/609965/detecting-when-the-mouse-is-not-moving

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could set an interval that decreases the value if the mouse does not move, and clear it when it moves, and reset it, something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var score = 0, decreaseInterval, intervalTime = 1000;

    function decrease() {
        if (score > 0) score--;
        $("#result").val(score);
    };

    decreaseInterval = setInterval(decrease, intervalTime);

    $("body").mousemove(function(){
        clearInterval(decreaseInterval);
        score ++;
        $("#result").val(score);
        decreaseInterval = setInterval(decrease, intervalTime);
        console.log(score);
    });
});
```

Here is a fiddle to demonstrate it working: https://jsfiddle.net/0swrae76/1/

Comment: Thinking about the JavaScript event loop I don't think you need to clearInterval and setInterval on every mouse move. Intead I would recommend setInterval once and use a boolean flag to manage things.

Answer (score 0):

Option: Use elapsed time. When the mouse is moved, check [now()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) vs last time mouse was moved. Use elapsed time to decrease the score in a chunk.

Comment: I am intersting in how to do the option 2.