# How to stop a background gif on hover and when the mouse isn't moving and resume the gif when its moving and on hover in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to stop the background gif when I am on another window because it uses up resources, is there a way to stop this when the body doesn't detect any mouse movement or hover.

An explanation of how it's done will be much be appreciated.

```css
body {
  background: url('https://i.pinimg.com/originals/f1/63/11/f16311fd0c32786525f471c685bc516e.gif') no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover; 
  height: 100%
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Background GIF</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Might be possible, but it will be way easier to use a video, where all those events are easy to attach.

Comment: looked up some ways.. and im seeing some volatile methods like `window.stop` and things that don't work with your code like the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3688460/stopping-gif-animation-programmatically so it's a good question

Comment: @NVRM is correct, you can't pause a gif. You can stop a gif, but it won't resume from the same place if you add it back again. Use a video instead.

Comment: Alright, do you know any tools that could convert a gif to a video?

Comment: You can convert your gif to png (at least one png), then you can change background from gif to png with css. It would not require much traffic I hope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @NVRM mentioned, "it will be way easier to use a video", taking that advice, I used [ezgif](https://ezgif.com/gif-to-mp4) to convert the gif to an mp4 video format which made the whole thing a lot easier.

I used the `window.onload` function to play the video automatically when it is first opened.

From there, I could use the `document.onmouseout` to pause the video when the cursor is out of the body/document and resume the video when the cursor is in the body/docenment with `document.onmousemove`. The `onmousemove` also allows the video to resume when it's paused from the lack of mouse movement.

To detect no mouse movement, I used this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/610000/14000013) that uses a `setInterval()` function to detect if the mouse hasn't moved in a specific time span, if so, it will execute the code within the function, which in this case, pausing the video.

To clear the no-mouse-detector function when the mouse is out of that window, I used `clearInterval()` inside the `document.onmouseout` function, otherwise, it keeps thinking the mouse isn't moving when it's not inside the body/document, wasting resources.

```js
const video = document.getElementById("background");

window.onload = function() {
  video.play();
};

document.onmouseout = function() {
  video.pause()
  clearInterval(timeout);
};

document.onmousemove = function() {
  video.play();
};

var timeout;
document.onmouseover = function () {
  clearInterval(timeout);
  timeout = setInterval(function () { 
    video.pause();
  }, 8888); 
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#background {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; 
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  min-width: 100%; 
  min-height: 100%; 
  width: auto; 
  height: auto;
  z-index: -1000; 
  transition: 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Background Test</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>

    <video  muted loop preload="auto" id="background">
      <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    
    
  </body>
</html>
```